# Business Central: How to display company or any other entity data into the page by using OData URL?

Tags: dynamics-business-central

We are having a requirement to display Company data into the page of Business Central by using OData URL and also pass the displayed data into the other system by using an API call. We have two questions right now to achieve this requirement.

1. How to display data in a Page using OData URL of business Central?
   --> In this case, we are assuming that we need to create an OData URL for this but we are not able to find anything about this.
2. On click of the Submit button we need to prepare the JSON of the displayed data in a page.
   --> In this case, we have a plan to make JSON of displayed data but we are struggling to make JSON from displayed data.

It would be great help if somebody could guide us what to do. It would be really very appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some code samples, screenshots or something else that explains in more detail what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the page on the page "web services", then you can see the soap or odata url in the same page,
more information at:

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dynamics365/business-central/across-how-publish-web-service)